# python3.6 aiohttp response times and sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

With python3.6 aiohttp is there a way to get all the following stats which i used to get using pycurl when making a request.

```
name_lookup_time = curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.NAMELOOKUP_TIME)
connect_time = curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.CONNECT_TIME)
app_connect_time = curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.APPCONNECT_TIME)
pre_transfer_time = curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.PRETRANSFER_TIME)
start_transfer_time = curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.STARTTRANSFER_TIME)
total_time = curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.TOTAL_TIME)
redirect_time = curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.REDIRECT_TIME)
redirect_cnt = curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.REDIRECT_COUNT)
total_size = curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.SIZE_DOWNLOAD)
```

Currently i'm using a pycurl multi implementation in my crawler to make the requests and then i have code which gathers detailed data for each request. To replace pycurl and learn something new. I am interested in replacing the pycurl multi code which makes the requests with a aiohttp client implementation.

Reading the aiohttp(https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse) documentation, i found that one can get the redirect_cnt by looking and counting the history Sequence which is part of the ClientResponse object.

```
history
A Sequence of ClientResponse objects of preceding requests (earliest request first) if there were redirects, an empty sequence otherwise.
```

I could do without most of the detailed time data. However i would like to gather total_time and total_size for my minimum requirement.

Comment: It is doubtful that you will get *all* those, as some seem quite curl-specific (e.g. `APPCONNECT_TIME`, `PRETRANSFER_TIME`). But if you reformulated the question to specify the actual requirements of your application, it might be easier to help.